# My PHP tag is not working, the code editor is not registering it

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

i have a php tag that is for some reason not working, when i first wrote the code it worked but after a while of me doing different things with the code it suddenly stopped working.

underneath here is my code

```php
<?php 
// Include the database configuration file  
require_once 'config.php'; 
 
// Get image data from database 
$result = $db->query("SELECT billede FROM billeder ORDER BY ret_id DESC"); 
?>

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){ ?> 
    <div class="gallery"> 
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?> 
            <img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['image']); ?>" /> 
        <?php } ?> 
    </div> 
<?php }else{ ?> 
    <p class="status error">Image(s) not found...</p> 
<?php } ?>
```

the problem is with this line. the question mark in the closing tag does not get registered as php.

```php
<img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['image']); ?>" />
```

I tried to go back but even then it still dit not work. its as if VS Code doesnt register it. does anyone know how to fix?

[image: this is a picture of how it looks in my code editor VS Code]

Comment: Can you share more details? What do you mean by "not registered"?

Comment: as you can se in the picture the question mark in the end tag for php on line 12 is not registering its green when it should be orange.

Comment: i dont get an error, it doesnt display the image and shows the piece of code after the question mark in the browser when it should just show the image im trying to post.

Comment: "it doesnt display the image" - that does not sound like a problem in your IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to echo the image tag, and then change it. So you have this line:

`echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" />';`

So in your code it would be:

```php
<?php 
// Include the database configuration file  
require_once 'config.php'; 
 
// Get image data from database 
$result = $db->query("SELECT billede FROM billeder ORDER BY ret_id DESC"); 
?>

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){ ?> 
    <div class="gallery"> 
        <?php 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" />';
        } 
        ?> 
    </div> 
<?php }else{ ?> 
    <p class="status error">Image(s) not found...</p> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Approach. Much Neater. Should have you sorted

```
<?php 
// Include the database configuration file  
require_once 'config.php'; 
 
// Get image data from database 
$result = $db->query("SELECT billede FROM billeder ORDER BY ret_id DESC"); 
?>

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0): ?> 

    <div class="gallery"> 
        <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?> 
            <img src="data:image/jpg;charset=utf8;base64,<?= base64_encode($row['image']); ?>" /> 
        <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </div> 

    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="status error">Image(s) not found...</p> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but sadly it did not work, i dont know if you saw the picture i uploaded at the bottom as well. but the question mark in the php closing tag is not registering for some reason. and wiht the code you sent it still doesnt...